# How to delete spaces beween letters that make up the same word?

Tags: python, nlp, token, tokenize

I basically have this a whole document that at some point includes the text = "R E S U L T", and after I tokenize it, the function tokenizes it letter by letter, so I would like to let the computer know "RESULT" must be tokenized as a whole word. Any ideas as to how to eliminate the spaces of the words separated by spaces in the document?

I was thinking somhow letting the computer know that if it finds a pattern like Letter+space+Letter+space maybe it could identify it?

this is the output I am getting:

R           NOUN      conj

E           NOUN      obj

S           PROPN     obj

U           PROPN     flat

L           PROPN     flat

T           PROPN     flat

and this is my code:

```
for value in dict.values():
    sentence= nlp2(value)
    for token in sentence:
        token_text = token.text
        token_pos = token.pos_
        token_dep = token.dep_
        print("{:<12}{:<10}{:<10}".format(token_text,token_pos,token_dep))
```

thanks so much!:)

Comment: Despite your tags, I am unable to determine what your `nlp2` function is doing. If you are using a package, please include the `include` line in your code. It may make more sense to adjust your text prior to sending it to a tokenizer. Is RESULT the only word you expect to be spaced out? If so, you probably could save further processing headaches by doing that conversion first.

Comment: yeah, i guess the example code I gave was not useful, I was planning on converting the text prior to the nlp2() call, and no RESULT is not the only word.. any idea how to adjust the text? thank you so much you again!

Comment: Are there any samples of other words with the spaces inserted? If there's a pattern maybe you could just look for when those starts, and only apply the space removal just in those cases. It could be a matter of searching a regular expression and removing all spaces, but then it might also depend on determining which spaces are significant.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the variable for sentence is the word 'RESULT' so you are iterating through the letters.  You would iterate through the words if sentence is a list, for example.  So inspect your value and sentence variables and see what you need to adjust.  See this toy example:

```
word_not_sentence = 'RESULT'
sentence_as_list_of_words = ['desired', 'RESULT']

for letter in word_not_sentence:
    print(letter)

for word in sentence_as_list_of_words:
    print(word)
```